# How to compile executables for Android 5.0 with standalone toolchain?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having lot's of executables (about 47mb) in my apk built with standalone android ndk toolchain. What should i do in order to compile PIE executables? Is it enough just add `-fPIE` to `CPPFLAGS`/`CFLAGS` and `-fPIE -pie` to `LDFLAGS` while configuring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be enough - that's what I've extracted from the NDK build scripts as well.

Comment: does it matter what NDK version is used? Can i use ndk 8c for example to create PIE-executables?

Comment: It shouldn't matter - at least NDK r8e has got the same declarations for `-fPIE -pie` in `build/core/build-binary.mk`. And even before that, it should work just fine as long as the gcc version supports it. Do note that binaries built with -pie don't run on older Android versions - IIRC such binaries only run on Android >= 4.1.

Comment: any modifications needed for .so libraries? Should i recompile them with specific flags like executables? How can i check i recompiled executables correctly (they are PIE), on linux?

Comment: You should build shared libraries with -fPIC, but there's no flag you need to specify when linking, like for the executables. Depending on your architecture you might get a build failure if you haven't used this flag, but if you already managed to build .so files, they should work just fine on Android 5.0.